# Overwriting animation? How can i fix it?

Tags: animation

guys.
I made a Walk Animation for my model (it's a Trooper with gun). Everything was fine. Than i created new animation (Idle)), and there also was great. But when I went back to the Walk animation, I saw that it changed. For example, the weapon has shifted, the hands have changed position. For some reason the two animations are mixed. And when I switched back to idle, there was a change there too. Only ctrl + z helped me. Apparently, the animations somehow overwrite each other?
Where can I see the setting that makes this evil?
Thanks.

Comment: maybe you need to create keyframes for all the bones at the beginning of the action so that when it plays the bone transforms are taken into account and not the previous ones?

Comment: i don't know. I am new in blender. Here is my boy: https://pasteall.org/blend/df76b881d94f4f888408eb38d55a083a I would be grateful if someone would take a look and help find the problem. (animations I redid, do not pay attention to the names)

Comment: try what I said, keyframe all your bones at the beginning of each action, then test again and tell me if it works fine

Comment: sorry for my stupidity, but I do not know how to do it(

Comment: Select the action in the Dope Sheet, put your cursor at the beginning of the timeline, make sure that your armature is in Pose mode, select all the bones in the 3D view and press "i" > Location, Rotation & Scale. Do the same for the other action.

Comment: when I did it on one animation, on the other animations these points appeared on their own.

Comment: when you load a second action, first press Alt S, Alt R and Alt G, it will reset all the bones, then they will all obey to their keyframes. Now you can select all at the first frame and keyframe.

Comment: So, when creating a new animation, I need to reset the parameters in the first frame every time so that the animations do not mix? Did I understand correctly? Thanks a lot.)

Comment: When you create a new action, it's probably better to keyframe all the bones (unless you have a reason to not do it of course) so that when you go from an action to another, the second action does not inherit the keyframes of the previous action, I'm not sure but I guess it's your problem here, isn't it?

Comment: It looks like it, but I'm not sure yet. Thanks for the help.)

Comment: (I meant keyframe the bones at the beginning of the action of course, otherwise the bones will inherit the keyframes from the previous action until they meet another keyframe)